# Win 11 BSOD DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION

Tags: bsod

I'm experiencing unexplained BSOD errors of type DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION.
Usually happens within a few minutes of booting, but can sometimes last a few hours.

x570 Auros Master
AMD Ryzen 9
2x 32G Corsair DDR 3200
Samsung 990 Evo Pro
RTX 4070 TI

I know drivers are a known culprit, and looking at the process in the dump file, I systematically removed applications that were "causing" it.
Unfortunately, this had no effect.

I replaced my NVMe drive with a brand new one.  Installed stock Windows and no additional drivers.  The issue remains.

I ran an 8 hour memtest on my RAM which came back good.

I bought a new graphics card (RTX 4070 TI), still having the errors.

One interesting thing I've noticed is that when the freeze happens, first Windows freezes and for a few seconds I can still move the mouse.

After that, sometimes it goes to the BSOD within a few seconds or minutes, but other times it simply never does.

I'm running out of hardware to replace!

I'm thinking of testing the power supply next.

I doubt it's the CPU since that memtest I ran uses all cores.

When the computer is on, I sometimes run HeavyLoad which runs just fine.

I'm thinking either the power supply or mother board, but I'm really at my wits end.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what the culprit could be?

Comment: I suggest it's the *x570 Auros Master* - is it the rev 1.0, or 1.1/1.2? What BIOS version?

Comment: actually, I just read what that stop code means - it's unlikely to be the motherboard or BIOS version

Comment: rev 1.2 and latest bios.  I was on F36 when the issue started, upgraded to F37g and still the issue.  I've just wiped and re-installed stock win 11.  No drivers again and going to wait till it happens and collect some dumps to see if I can get a clue.  Problem is that sometimes it takes hours for the issue to manifest ... sometimes minutes.

Comment: I'm going to spend a few days and collect some data re the pattern of bsod.  I'm having some suspicions and hopefully it'll give a clue.